# Decimal to binary in C using %2

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
   int num = 11, i = 10;
   char s[10];
   while (num != 0)
   {
      if (num % 2 == 0)
      {
         num = num / 2;
         s[i - 1] = 0;
         i = i - 1;
      }
      if (num % 2 == 1)
      {
         num = (num - 1) / 2;
         s[i - 1] = 1;
         i = i - 1;
      }
      return s[10];
   }
   printf("\n %s", s[10]);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Hi, I am pretty new to C code so maybe im overlooking something really simple, but when i run this code it does not show anything as output. And I believe there are more mistakes which could have been atleast simplified..

Comment: `return s[10];` exits the program, before the printing.

Comment: Also print the newline *last* in the output.

Comment: And learn the difference between a single element in an array, and the whole array. Perhaps get some good beginners books as well.

Comment: If you want to print `s` as a string, you need to be putting characters into the array, `s[i-1] = '0';` and `s[i-1] = '1';`. Not integers 0 and 1. You also need to zero-terminate `s` for a proper C string. So start with `s[--i] = '\0';` (or `s[--i] = 0;`). before your `while` loop. For "cleaner" code, you can replace, `s[i - 1] = 0;
        i = i - 1;` with `s[--i] = '0';`, for example.

Comment: a integer has (in most modern architectures) 32 bits, not 10.  And also need room for the trailing NUL byte

Comment: I think you meant `#include <stdio.h>` instead of `#include "stdafx.h"` (which despite its name, is some kind of non-standard platform header).

Comment: Compliers warn at different levels.  By enabling all warnings, at compilation time, your code would have warned about `printf("\n %s", s[10]);` and possible others.  Save debug time.  Enable all warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 11, i = 0, j = 0;
    char s[33];
    char be_s[33];

    do
    {
        s[i] = num % 2 ? '1' : '0';
        num = num / 2;
        i++;
    } while (num != 0);

    s[i] = '\0';

    printf("Little endian number: %s\n",s);

    for(j = 0 ; j < i ; j++)
    {
        be_s[j] = s[(i - 1) - j];
    }

    be_s[j] = '\0';
    printf("Big endian number: %s\n",be_s);
    return 0;
}
```

As someone already explained you have more than one issue:

1. Size of s: how big is the number you want to convert? Int (usually) is 32 bit, so you need 32 char to write it. Also you need a special character to end the string, '\0', so a char array of 33 elements should be ok for this exercise
2. Endianness: As you probably noted you want to express it with the more significant bit on the left. The problem is that you cannot know where the first 1 will be. An option is to revert the bit order after evaluating the number
3. return inside a while: the while is not a function, if you "return" you are exiting the main function, thus closing the program
4. s[3]: this is not a string, is the 4th value of the string. If you want the pointer to the start of the string you can use `s`, or if you want to start reading the string from element `n` you can use `&s[n - 1]` (&= memory address, of n element of string s; please note that array starts from element 0)
5. char value of 0 and 1: as other said `char 0` is different from `char '0'` the first is the element 0 in the ascii table, the second is the elemen *representing zero* in the ascii table

There's a lot more to say, if you don't understand my example just ask

Comment: If `num == 0`, this code outputs `"Little endian number: \n"`.  Consider `do 
    {
        s[i] = num % 2 ? '1' : '0';
        num = num / 2;
        i++;
    } while (num != 0);` to insure `s[]` has at least one digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (num % 2 == 0)
{
    num = num / 2;
    s[i - 1] = 0;
    i = i - 1;
}
if (num % 2 == 1)
{
    num = (num - 1) / 2;
    s[i - 1] = 1;
    i = i - 1;
}
```

Besides returning right after these statements (which causes an immediate program exit), here you either set `s`'s characters to '\0' or '\1'. None of them is printable; moreover, '\0' signifies string end. Change literals `0` and `1` into the appropriate `'0'` and `'1'`.

Moreover, you need to put a zero character (`'\0'`) into `s` to terminate the string, and increase `s`'s size to accommodate for that extra character. The easiest way is to initialize `s` to all zeroes from start: `char s[11] = {'\0'};`.

And remove that `return s[10];` from the loop body.

Comment: `char s[11] = {};` is not valid C. (Although it is valid C++).

Comment: Looks quite allowed here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization

Comment: that epitomises why you should not trust what you read on the internet. It’s been allowed since C++11 and is yet to be incorporated into C.

Comment: The cppreference link you quote says "int a[3] = {}; // invalid C but valid C++"

Comment: Okay, you win, I've added a single zero char.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues.

- The instructions in the `while` loop are executed exactly once, and then the program exits, since you call `return s[10]` at the end of the loop. Returning from `main` effectively quits the program.
- The `%s` printf token expects a string, which in c is just an array of char's (either char * or char[]), but you pass it a single char (s[10]). If you want to print `s` just use `printf("%s\n", s);`
- To be more precise, a proper c-string of length N is a sequence (that is, an array) of N char's followed by an end-of-string character, '\0'. So, if you want to build a string of size 10 "by hand", you first define a properly-sized array, `char s[11]`. You then set `s[10] = '\0';` and can use the 0-9 indices to modify all the other char's that make up the string.
- You need to put characters (`'1'` and `'0'`) rather than integers (not `1` and `0`) in your char's.

Comment: "Since internally char's are treated like integers which are converted to characters through the ASCII table" - where does the C standard state that?